# Extendscript with Photoshop: Importing an image

Tags: photoshop, extendscript

I'm trying to select some image files via a prompt, then add those files to the active document. Here's what I have so far:

```
#target photoshop

doc = app.activeDocument;

// choose image files
var files = File.openDialog(undefined,undefined,true);

// for each image, add to new layer and insert into doc
for (var file in files) {
    var layer = doc.artLayers.add();
    layer.image = file; // this doesn't work.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's `layer.image`? `ArtLayer` doesn't have this property. Maybe placing will work better in your case:

```
doc = app.activeDocument;

// choose image files
var files = File.openDialog(undefined, undefined, true);

// for each image, add to new layer and insert into doc
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    var layer = placeImage(files[i]);
}

function placeImage(imageFile)
{
    var desc554 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc554.putPath(cTID('null'), imageFile);
    desc554.putEnumerated(cTID('FTcs'), cTID('QCSt'), cTID('Qcsa'));
    var desc555 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc555.putUnitDouble(cTID('Hrzn'), cTID('#Pxl'), 0.000000);
    desc555.putUnitDouble(cTID('Vrtc'), cTID('#Pxl'), 0.000000);
    desc554.putObject(cTID('Ofst'), cTID('Ofst'), desc555);
    executeAction(cTID('Plc '), desc554, DialogModes.NO);

    return activeDocument.activeLayer
};

function cTID(s)
{
    return app.charIDToTypeID(s);
};

function sTID(s)
{
    return app.stringIDToTypeID(s);
};
```

Also Photoshop doesn't like when `for...in` loops are used on Array (sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't: in case of `File` object it doesn't work)